# In 《猫城记》 (Cat Country), is 迷叶 an allusion to opium?

Tags: allusions, chinese-language, lao-she, cat-country

I'm re-reading the Chinese novel 《猫城记》 by 老舍.  On page 33, referring to the cat people of cat country, it says:

> 五百年前，他们是种地收粮，不懂什么叫迷叶。忽然有个外国人把它带到猫国来。最初只有上等人吃得起，后来他们把迷树也搬运了来，于是大家全吃入了瘾。不到五十年的工夫，不吃它的人是例外了。吃迷叶是多么舒服，多么省事的；可是有一样，吃了之后虽然精神焕发，可是手脚不爱动，于是种地的不种了，作工的不作了，大家闲散起来。
>
> *Google Translate (plus my annotations)*: Five hundred years ago, they cultivated the land and harvested grain, so they didn't know what a 迷叶 (intoxicating leaf) was. Suddenly a foreigner brought it to the cat country. At first, only the upper classes could afford it, but later they brought the 迷树 (intoxicating tree), and everyone became addicted to it. In less than fifty years, people who do not eat it are exceptions. How comfortable and trouble-free it is to eat lost leaves; but there is one thing, although after eating, although the energy is refreshed, the hands and feet do not like to move, so the farmers stopped planting, the workers stopped working, and everyone became idle.

This description seems to have commonality with the [opium trade](https://www.britannica.com/topic/opium-trade):

> **opium trade**, in Chinese history, the traffic that developed in the 18th and 19th centuries in which Western countries, mostly Great Britain, exported opium grown in India and sold it to China. The British used the profits from the sale of opium to purchase such Chinese luxury goods as porcelain, silk, and tea, which were in great demand in the West, while addiction to opium became widespread in China, leading to social and economic problems there.

Maybe I'm reading too much in to this, however.

**Question**: In 《猫城记》 (Cat Country), is 迷叶 an allusion to opium?

Comment: Does SE have a Chinese community? You might consider posing your query to *Language Log* a blog maintained by a U of Pennsylvania linguistics professor who is also a Chinese language specialist. https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/